# Infinite sum of squared normal random variables with variances tending to zero

Tags: probability, chi-squared

Let $Z_n \sim N(0, n^{-1})$ be independent. I would like to know what I can say about the distribution of

$$Z := \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} Z_n^2$$

Each $Z_n^2$ can be written as $\frac{Y_n}{n}$,where the $Y_n$ are i.i.d. $\chi^2_1$. However, I am not sure how we could then get a closed form for the distribution of $Z$. Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: I think it should be "Each $Z_n^2$ can be written as $\frac{Y_n}{n^2}$,where the $Y_n$....".

Comment: @mag It should definitely be $Z_n^2$, but the numerator of $n$ is correct if the OP intended $n^{-1}$ to denote $Z_n$'s variance, rather than the rarer convention for the second argument of $N$ to be a standard deviation.

Comment: You're right regarding the numerator, sry. I'm not sure about this: maybe you could use that the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables is given by the convolution of probability distributions.

Comment: The most I can tell you about this distribution is its mean is infinite and its characteristic function is $\prod_n(1-2it/n)^{-1/2}$, but [it turns out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307167/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-wilcoxon-signed-ranked-test-statistic) $\sum_nnY_n$ is well-studied, which is different but an interesting comparison.

Comment: You're right I should have said "Each $Z_n^2$." Sorry for the typo, I've edited that in the OP